# what's the difference between a terminal services server and an application server

Tags: cloud

I was watching this youtube video about cloud computing by eli the computer guy 
and his description for the application server is a lot like how the terminal 
services server work. Is there a fine line between both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A terminal server is a hardware device or server that provides terminals (PCs, printers, and other devices) with a common connection point to a local or wide area network.

An application server is a software framework that provides both facilities to create web applications and a server environment to run them